# Initiate file download at interval

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a script that will automatically initiate the download of a remote file at set intervals (say every 30mins) and save the download files to a directory.

Done searches here and Google, no help. Any input will really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think that's possible, seems terribly insecure

Comment: may be cron job will help

Comment: Client side JavaScript does not allow this because it would be the worst security flaw in the history of mankind. What are you trying to accomplish here? If you are using Node.js on a local server, that would be a different story.

Comment: I think learning a bit of Java and creating a Java applet to do this might be the only viable browser-based solution here

Comment: *what am trying to accomplish*  there is a remote file (website.com/file.zip) and a system that checks how many times this file have been downloaded, so instead of downloading this remote file manual until a set threshold to trigger an events, want to have a script do the downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a link and clicking it with Javascript.

```js
function download(){
  document.getElementById("link").click();
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" download="page.html" style="display: none;" id="link"></a>
<input type="button" value="Download Google as html" onclick="download();"/>
```